# C++ OpenCV assertion failed error

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a code that copies pixels from one image to another and arranges them differently, but I get an error

**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed 0 && size.height>0> in cv::imshow, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261**

Here's the code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
Mat src = imread("srcImg.jpg", 1);
Mat dst = imread("dstImg.jpg", 1);
int srcH = src.rows; int srcW = src.cols;
int dstH = dst.rows; int dstW = src.cols;

double alpha;
int r = 50;

for (int i = 0; i < srcH; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < srcW; j++) {
        alpha = i / r;
        dst.at<uchar>(dstW / 2 * cos(alpha), 
            (dstH / 2 + r) * sin(alpha)) = src.at<uchar>(i, j);
    }
}

imshow("Source", src);
imshow("Result", dst);

return 0;
```

What can be a problem here?

Comment: You don't read the image correctly. Check the image path

Comment: Thanks! That helped with and error, but still result image is empty and pixels don't copy. Can it be a problem with Mat.at() method?

Comment: Use a debugger. You have integer truncation for `alpha`, and probably also when computing matrix indices. The matrix indices cannot be negative, so check the indices computation is correct. Also you need to access with `.at<Vec3b>()`

Comment: alpha = i / r;   You are dividing 2 integers together which truncate the result. Try alpha = (double)i/r

Comment: Tried to cast alpha to double and that worked, thanks!